# How to store part of a plist to a file and then merge this to another plist?

Tags: macos, plist, macos-sierra, plistbuddy

I need to extract part of a plist, store this in a file and then later load / merge this saved portion into another plist, overwriting an existing key with its accompanying keys and values.

I understand that `PlistBuddy` helps the process dramatically as you can read a portion a key with its subkeys via:
`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :KeyName" /path/to/some.plist`

But it's not clear if you can simply use file redirection here to save the output and then reload it via the `Merge` command with the accompanying plist to insert or not.

An example of the commands would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the following process can be followed to modify a plist with merged values:

```
# Get contents that you want to store:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Print :KeyYouWant" /path/to/plist_with_key_set_you_want.plist

# Merge the contents of the saved file to the other plist:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Merge plist_with_key_set_you_want.plist :KeyToMergeInto" /path/to/destination.plist
```